# What is the right relative pronoun in the following sentence?

Tags: pronoun, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

> Ich möchte wieder in dem Gasthaus einen Kaffee trinken, in _____ wir samstags immer gegangen sind.

I think it is ***das*** because the antecedent is ***dem Gasthaus*** which original form is *das Gasthaus*. So it translates to "which we always went (into) on Saturdays"?
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: "das" sounds good, though I am not sure about your reasoning. I believe it depends on the last part of the sentence. Compare for instance with the following sentence: Ich möchte wieder in dem Gasthaus einen Kaffee trinken, in dem wir uns getroffen haben.

Comment: What about..... Das ist doch der, ___ wir im Hauptseminar kennen gelernt haben, nicht?.... is it den?

Comment: Yes, "den". So taking a second look at these three examples, aren't these just Akkusativ ("Wohin sind wir samstags immer gegangen?"), Dativ ("Wo haben wir uns getroffen?") and another Akkusativ ("Wen haben wir getroffen?")

Comment: @user1583209, I also sometimes do it, but please don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: yep, "das" is correct. cant tell you why, though :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *das* is correct here.

**The gender and number (plural/singular) is determined by the word to which the relative pronoun relates. The case is determined by the way the relative pronoun is used in the sentence.**

In your example *das* is in the 4. case (accusative) because it answers “In welches Kaffee sind wir samstags immer gegangen?”.

If we used *Bar* the sentence would have to be like

> Ich möchte wieder in der *Bar* einen Kaffee trinken, in *die* wir samstags immer gegangen sind.

because *Bar* is feminin.

If the relative clause made use of the relative pronoun as subject, it had to be in the 1. case of course. E.g.

> Ich möchte wieder in dem Gasthaus einen Kaffee trinken, das so bequeme Sessel hat.

---

It makes no difference whether you use *welcher/welche/welches* or *die/der/das* as relative pronoun. *welcher/welche/welches* is probably regarded as more refined language but modern style guides recommend to prefer *die/der/das*.

Answer (score -2):

The actually grammatically correct word to use here is "welches":

Ich möchte wieder in dem Gasthaus einen Kaffee trinken, in **welches** wir samstags immer gegangen sind.

However, you can replace it with "das", as that is allowed, since it has the right form; "welches" makes it more clear that you mean "das Gasthaus".

Comment: How is "welches" more clear than "das" here? How could one misunderstand the sentence with "das"?